# Join 2 tables with custom metadata in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model, and a Goal model. The Goal model has a name, and a type column, which has the following three records right now.

```
name           | type
------------------------
Read Novels    | Reading
Read Newspaper | Reading
Write Reviews  | Writing
```

Now I want to provide each user, an interface to fill in the number of hours they spend on this activity every month (`hours_per_month`), and the number of different days they do it (`days_per_month`).

Ideally, I'd want to work with the data like

```
current_user = User.find(params[:id])

current_user.goals.each do |goal|
  puts goal.name
  puts goal.type
  puts goal.hours_per_month
  puts goal.days_per_month
end
```

How should I create this new table/model, that joins the Goals to User, and have access to the static Goal attributes, and the user filled values, like the code sample above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an `Activity` model and give it a table definition like:

activities:

- user_id
- goal_id
- hours_per_month
- days_per_month

Then add to:

```
User
  has_many :activities
  has_many :goals, :through => :activity

Goal
  has_many :activities
  has_many :users, :through => :activity

Activity
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :goal
```

You can use a generator to do most of the work iirc.

Answer (score 1):

**Table goals_users**

```
column: user_id
column: goal_id
column: hours_worked
```

**Models:**

**User:**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :goals
```

**Goals:**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

def hours_per_month
  #calculate
end

def hours_per_day
  #calculate
end
```

Obviously set up the additional columns outside the join however you like.

**Additional**

In any model using AR joins you'll need to access the intermediary record directly.